# How many vectors $(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})$ are there for which each $x_{i}$ is a positive integer?

Tags: combinatorics

How many vectors $(x_{1},x_{2}, \cdots ,x_{n})$ are there for which each $x_{i}$ is a positive integer such that $1 ≤ x_{i} ≤ k$ and $x_{1} < x_{2} < \cdots < x_{n}$? Assume that $k \ge n$.

**My Attempt:**

I guess the interpretation of the question is pretty straightforward, and with my scope of knowledge within Permutations and Combinations, what is the best approach for this question?

The only way I can visualise this situation is through ${}_nC_1$, but I am pretty sure that isn't the way to go, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we want to construct a vector which satisfies this problem. The first step is to choose $n$ distinct numbers from a set of $k$ numbers. Once we have chosen these $n$ distinct numbers, note that their order after sorting is unique. So each choice of $n$ distinct numbers corresponds to only one unique solution. So the answer is simply $k \choose n$.